# Add a text lable to Added image object in fabric js

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

Is there a way to add a text filed (as a label) to image object in fabric js.when user drag and drop a image to canvas the label should added.This should not added as object groups.

Comment: What is the problem with group?

Comment: It works. But I need to save the data for individual objects.

Comment: while saving, destory the group and add all object to canvas ,then save.

Comment: Is there a way to make them group again after save.

Comment: `new fabric.Group(...objects)`